# How to display last 2 items from a table in c# using html

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to display the last two items added to my table in my Index.cshtml.

```cs
public class News
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string Titre { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Image { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Now using this I wanna display the last two "news" added using the date.

```hmtl
<!--Last item #1-->
<div class="newsBlock" style="clear:left;">
    <img src="" />
    <p></p>
</div>

<!--Last item #2-->
<div class="newsBlock" style="clear:right;">
    <img src="" />
    <p></p>
</div>
<p style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</p>
```

I tried using a razor forloop but couldn't do it somehow I ended up with this...

```cs
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @{var test = Model.OrderByDescending(modelItem => model.Date).Take(2).ToArray();}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderByDescending(modelItem => modelItem.Date).Take(2).ToList())
{
    <div class="newsBlock" style="clear:left;">
        <img src="@item.Image" />
        <p>@item.Title</p>
    </div>
}
```

**OR**

better way in your controller

```
public Action Index()
{
    return View(db.News.OrderByDescending(modelItem => modelItem.Date).Take(2).ToList());
}
```

View

```
@model IEnumerable<News>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="newsBlock" style="clear:left;">
        <img src="@item.Image" />
        <p>@item.Title</p>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you mister.

However if I wanted to put the second date with clear:right, how would that work.